# Firebase Analytics does not show AnalyticsEventItem

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

In a Flutter application, I'm trying to track some user activities. The app uses GoogleAnalytics and some Firebase features. Thus it uses Firebase Analytics to measure statistics.

For example, I would like to see which item (product) added wishlist mostly. So I wrote this code to track if user add a specific item to their wishlist:

```
  Future<void> addToWishlist({
    required int productId,
    required String name,
    required int brandId,
    required int categoryId,
    required double price,
  }) async {
    var analyticsEventItem = AnalyticsEventItem(
      itemId: productId.toString(),
      itemName: name,
      itemBrand: brandId.toString(),
      itemCategory: categoryId.toString(),
    );
    await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logAddToWishlist(
      value: price,
      currency: "USD",
      items: [analyticsEventItem],
    );
  }
```

In dashboard, it shows value and currency correctly but I could not find any item under `add_to_wishlist` event.

Is there something wrong I did? Where can I see these items?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Currently, `item` parameter is not yet supported to be displayed in the Analytics dashboard. However, you can access this data in [BigQuery export](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en#:%7E:text=item_name%2C%20and%20item_brand.-,Items,-items).